Cant Import images from table on a website using importhtml
I am trying to import data from the folowwing page:
https://sofifa.com/squad/1697556
I would love to also import the picture of the player and also the
national flag that is in the table.
As of now i use =IMPORTHTML( "https://sofifa.com/squad/1697556", "table", 1) but that dosent get me the pictures.
It returns the following:
Table with data
Is there any way to either grab the URL or the actual image.
I tried the solution from Question but couldnt get it to work.


You may try:
=let(url,"https://sofifa.com/squad/1697556", Σ,importhtml(url,"table",),
 index(hstack(vstack("DP",image(substitute(importxml(url,"//figure[@class='avatar']/img/@data-src"),"60.png","180.png"))),
        choosecols(Σ,2,3,4,5),
        vstack("Flag",image(substitute(importxml(url,"//figure[@class='avatar small transparent']/img/@data-src"),"30.png","90.png"))),
        choosecols(Σ,6,7,8,9))))


